# Use jquery to dynamically number table columns diagonally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi there fellow coders,

I'm looking to find a way to fill a pre-built dynamic blank table with numbering (and colouring if possible) like so:

[image: 5x5 grid] 

As you can see the numbering is ascending order diagonally. I know there's probably some way to calculate the number based on the tables td index but can't quite figure out how to do that for every column diagonally. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** Ok back from my Holidays. Thanks to all you clever people for your replies. As I'm sure you've all had to experience the pain in the neck clients can be, I've been told the spec has changed(again). This being the case I've had to put the grid/matrix into a database and output using a pivot table. Every square has to be customizable color-wise.

Nothing is going to waste though I have learnt quite a few nifty new javascript/jquery tricks from your responses I didn't know about before, so thanks, and I'll be sure to pay it forward :)

Here's what I came up with in the end.

[image: custom grid]

Comment: Colouring's easy once you have the numbers in place hehe:-)

Comment: In your diagram, why is 15 orange rather than yellow? Also, I take it you want an algorithm that can handle different sizes, but will the table always be a square?

Comment: Quick&Dirty: http://jsfiddle.net/Seybsen/ZdwV4/ but may be a good starting point for you.

Comment: @Seybsen: But the numbers are not increasing in the diagonal order.

Comment: @Furqan: I'm assuming that is why Seybsen said "good starting point" and added it as a comment not an answer!

Comment: So random that there was a ﾂ in the question before it was edited??!

Answer (score 3):

Given you said "colouring if possible" I'll provide an example solution that doesn't do colours quite the way you want (it does it in a way that I found easier to code and more attractive to look at) but which does handle all the numbering correctly for varying table sizes.

The function below assumes the table already exists; in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7NZt3/2) I've included code that generates a table to whatever size you specify and then calls the function below to do the numbering and colours.

```
function numberDiagonally(tableId) {
    var rows = document.getElementById(tableId).rows,
        numRows = rows.length,
        numCols = rows[0].cells.length,
        sq = numRows + numCols - 1,
        d, x, y,
        i = 1,
        dc,
        c = -1,
        colors = ["green","yellow","orange","red"];

    diagonalLoop:
    for (d = 0; d < sq; d++) {
        dc = "diagonal" + d;
        for (y = d, x = 0; y >= 0; y--, x++) {
            if (x === numCols)
                continue diagonalLoop;
            if (y < numRows)
                $(rows[y].cells[x]).html(i++).addClass(dc);
        }
    }
    for (d = 0; d < sq; d++)
        $(".diagonal" + d).css("background-color", colors[c=(c+1)%colors.length]);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7NZt3/2

The general idea I came up with was to imagine a square twice as big as whichever of the x and y dimensions is bigger and then use a loop to create diagonals from the left edge of that bounding square going up and to the right - i.e., in the order you want the numbers. **EDIT:** Why twice as big as longer side? Because that's the first thing that came into my head when I started coding it and it worked (note that the variable `i` that holds the numbers that get displayed is not incremented for the imaginary cells). Now that I've had time to think, I realise that my `sq` variable can be set precisely to one less than the number of rows plus the columns - a number that ends up rather smaller for non-square tables. Code above and fiddle updated accordingly.

Note that the background colours could be set directly in the first loop, but instead I opted to assign classes and set the loops for each class later. Seemed like a good idea at the time because it meant individual diagonals could be easily selected in jQuery with a single class selector.

Explaining exactly how the rest works is left as an exercise for the reader...

UPDATE - this version does the colouring more like you asked for: http://jsfiddle.net/7NZt3/1/ (in my opinion not as pretty, but each to his own).

Comment: I love the diagonal loop though!

Comment: Thanks Royi and @JasperMogg - Yes, the colouring isn't quite right, but then the colouring in the question doesn't really make sense, I mean, _three_ diagonals of green and _two_ in the other colours? And what's up with cell 15? (OP could always take [the version](http://jsfiddle.net/7NZt3/1/) I did with adjacent diagonals in a common colour and modify it to force three in green to start...)

Comment: Cell 15 was orange because at the time I wanted 8 yellow and 8 orange. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rodneyrehm/mSbXQ/) populates an existing table with numbers and colors. It is not limited to being a 5x5 table. I didn't understand the logic of `15` being orange rather than yellow, so I simply grouped the diagonal cells into color regions.

---

```
// we're assuming the table exists
var $table = $('table'),
    // cache the rows for quicker access
    $rows = $table.find('tr'),
    // determine number of rows
    _rows = $rows.length,
    // determine number of cells per row
    _cols = $rows.first().children().length,
    // determine total number of cells
    max = _rows * _cols,
    // current diagonal offset (for coloring)
    d = 1,
    // current row
    r = 0,
    // current cell
    c = 0;

for (var i=1; i <= max; i++) {
    // identify and fill the cell we're targeting
    $rows.eq(r).children().eq(c)
        .addClass('d' + d)
        .text(i);

    if (i < max/2) {
        // in the first half we make a "line-break" by 
        // moving one row down and resetting to first cell
        if (!r) {
            r = c + 1;
            c = 0;
            d++;
            continue;
        }
    } else {
        // in the second half our "line-break" changes to
        // moving to the last row and one cell to the right
        if (c + 1 == _cols) {
            c = 1 + r;
            r = _rows -1;
            d++;
            continue;
        }
    }

    r--;
    c++;
}
```

Comment: I like the colour scheme you chose :-) Very Kuler :-p

Comment: I have a feeling this is an assignment/homework and going back telling the examiner, their colouring scheme doesn't make sense is preparing for failure. I'm sure the intention is to see if the developer excludes colours due to the added difficulty or includes them as stated. Off course, this is assuming this question was part of an assignment/homework.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - If this question were given to me as an assignment/homework the first thing I'd do is ask the lecturer whether the intention is to write code that copes with different table sizes and if so how the colour scheme should work. If I couldn't get clarification (for whatever reason) I'd most likely submit a two-part answer, the first part showing how to achieve exactly that 5x5 result, and the second part generic enough to do any table size... (Otherwise you don't need an algorithm to do it, you just need a template.)

Comment: @nnnnnn teacher's pet, eh? ;-) What sort of level of homework is this anyway?

Comment: @JasperMogg - Not really a teacher's pet: (I know you're just kidding around, but) I didn't take computing classes until the last two years of high school and then at university, and by then I'd learned to (at least try to) take my assignments seriously. Though sadly I wouldn't have received _this_ question as homework since I finished university in the early 90s before JavaScript existed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsFiddle that does what you asked for - http://jsfiddle.net/jaspermogg/MzNr8/8/

I took the liberty of making it a little bit user-customisable; it's interesting to see how long it takes the browser to render a 1000x1000 table using this method :-D

Assuming that each cell has an id of `[column]x[row]`, here are teh codez for how to fill in the numbers of a square table of side length `sidelength`.

```
//populate the cells with numbers according to the spec
function nums(){

    var xpos = 0
    var ypos = 0     
    var cellval = 1

        for(i=0;i<2*sidelength;i++){

            if(i >= sidelength){

                ypos = sidelength - 1
                xpos = 1 + i - sidelength
                $('td#' + xpos + 'x' + ypos).text(cellval)
                cellval = cellval + 1        

                while(xpos + 1 < sidelength){
                    ypos = ypos-1
                    xpos = xpos+1
                    $('td#' + xpos + 'x' + ypos).text(cellval)
                    cellval = cellval + 1
                }

            } else {

                ypos = i
                xpos = 0        
                $('td#' + xpos + 'x' + ypos).text(cellval)
                cellval = cellval + 1

                while(!(ypos-1 < 0)){
                    ypos = ypos-1
                    xpos = xpos+1
                    $('td#' + xpos + 'x' + ypos).text(cellval)
                    cellval = cellval + 1
                }        

            }

        }

}
```

And here they are for how to colour the bugger.

```
// color the cells according to the spec
function cols(){
        if(+$('td#0x0').text() === 99){
        return false
        } else {
            $('td').each(function(index, element){
                if(+$(this).text() > 22)
                {
                    $(this).attr("bgcolor", "red")
                } 
                if(+$(this).text() <= 22)
                {
                    $(this).attr("bgcolor", "orange")
                }
                if(+$(this).text() <= 14)
                {
                    $(this).attr("bgcolor", "yellow")
                }
                if(+$(this).text() <= 6)
                {
                    $(this).attr("bgcolor", "green")
                }
            })
        }
}
```

Enjoy, eh? :-)

Comment: +1 for following the requirements without questioning the logic behind the given colour scheme. Though it says `colouring if possible`, I'm sure that if one decides to include colouring it should follow the outlined requirements.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - Not a criticism of Jasper, who as you say implemented exactly the colour scheme shown in the question, but the OP's phrase "dynamic blank table" implied that the size could vary, and given the OP hasn't (yet) come back to explain the logic behind the colour scheme shown (What's with the orange 15?) it's not obvious how it could be applied to other sizes - it seems contrary to the strict diagonals of the numbering.

Comment: P.S. If it can be assumed the table will always be 5x5 you don't need an algorithm to calculate diagonals, you can just use a pre-defined array of 25 elements with the number and colour to be applied to each cell...

Comment: Fair points, @nnnnnn . But more fun to make it a bit customisable :-) After all, we're not getting marked ;-)

Comment: Yep. That's why in my answer I stated up front that I'd done the colouring a different way. Can't have both customisable sizing and a colour scheme based on rules that aren't explained, so I went with customisable sizing...

Comment: @nnnnnn: all good points. And good work on the update in your answer.